# WPF application

Tags: wpf

Hi I am new to WPF.. Can any one tell what is the difference between standalone applications and XAML browser applications (XBAPs) and how it differs in handling navigation and other stuff..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tip: forget XBAP, its going. Its all about WPF and Silverlight now.

Silverlight is basically a subset of WPF, there are some limitations and restrictions.

But the core system of these two is the same so if you are a beginner, just pick one. Learn XAML and you'll get two for the price of one.  It'll be some time before you have to worry about the differences.

Comment: Everyone says XAML. Is that Visual C# or another WPF Application. I was wondering what the difference is in these. I normally use Java at work but I want to learn something new at home.

Comment: XAML is still in use for Win8 and Win Phone but for a learning project you might want to look at HTML5 instead.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference i know of is that one runs as a normal .exe file and XBAPs run in the browser but with restricted access to the host system.

Comment: Can the .exe file run in a browser? There is a C# application and a WPF application. What is the real different?

Comment: @DougHauf im sorry but i don't understand what you are saying? but you could read up on it on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What I was asking is the WPF application able to run in a browser.